# Updating specific markers on google maps with Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

I'm using google maps on my website, basically what i'm trying to do is to show markers on my map, I'm retrieving an object of `Drivers` from Firebase, and then I retrieve the latitude and longitude of each `Driver` and display it on the map.
So I've two questions:

**1-** Whenever the latitude and longitude of each `Driver` change, I want to update their markers on the map, not all the markers, **just the markers of those drivers who got their latitude and longitude changed**, how can I do that ?

**2-** I know that `child_changed` in Firebase returns a snapshot of the child that was changed, but what if, let's say 100 child changed at the same time, **would it return all the 100 child one at a time** ?

---

Here are some samples of my code:

This function returns all the `Drivers` and show them as markers on the map

```
    function getDrivers(){

     var database = firebase.database().ref().child('allDrivers');
     database.on('value',function(snapshot) {
        var array = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          array.push(childData);
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(array[i].latPosition), lng: parseFloat(array[i].longPosition)};
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latlng,
           map: map,
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
           icon:'img/goodambulance.jpg'
         });    }  });
```

This is not best practice, because once a child change, it'll return all the child in `allDrivers` node, I just want it to return the child that was changed, and then update its location on the map.
So what changes should i make in my code ?

Comment: can you check my post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538486/retrieving-google-maps-locations-to-markers-from-firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `child` event listener instead of `value` and i created two objects, equivalent to `hashMap`, which takes a key and a value
One for the `Drivers` object and one for the markers

```
var driversMap = {};
var markersMap = {};
```

Inside `child_added` I put the `Drivers` object and the unique key associated to it which i retrieved from the `snapShot` inside my `driversMap`

```
driversMap[childKey] = childData;
```

And then i retrieve the latitude and longitude and add the markers.
Also i add the unique key of each driver to their associated markers using `id`

```
var latlng = {lat:parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].latPosition), lng: parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].longPosition)};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: 'img/goodambulance.png',
      id: childKey
    });
```

And finally, inside `child_changed` I get the key of the object inside `snapShot` and search for it inside `driversMap` and `markersMap`, and then i delete the outdated driver object and re-add it to `driversMap`, then I get the driver's latitude and longitude and use `setPosition` to re-position the marker

```
delete driversMap[childKey];
driversMap[childKey] = childData;
      var latlng = {lat:parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].latPosition), lng: 
       parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].longPosition)};
      markersMap[childKey].setPosition(latlng);
```

Here's the full code:

```js
    function getDrivers(){
      var arr = [];
      var database = firebase.database().ref().child('allDrivers');
      database.on("child_added",function(snapshot){
        var childKey = snapshot.key;
        var childData = snapshot.val();
        driversMap[childKey] = childData;
        var latlng = {lat:parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].latPosition), lng: parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].longPosition)};
    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: 'img/goodambulance.png',
          id: childKey
        });
        markersMap[marker.id] = marker;
    
      });
      database.on("child_changed",function(snapshot){
        var childData = snapshot.val();
        console.log(childData);
        var childKey = snapshot.key;
        if(childKey in driversMap && childKey in markersMap)
        {
          delete driversMap[childKey];
          driversMap[childKey] = childData;
          var latlng = {lat:parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].latPosition), lng: 
           parseFloat(driversMap[childKey].longPosition)};
          markersMap[childKey].setPosition(latlng);
          delete markersMap[childKey];
          
           }
      });
    
    }
```